# Bundle.main.path(forResource:ofType:inDirectory:) returns nil when directory and filename are correct

Tags: ios, swift

```
let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[indexPath.row], ofType: ".mp3", inDirectory: "Songs")!
```

Returns nil. songs[indexPath.row] returns the correct name, as it is exactly in the folder named "Songs". The songs folder is blue and shows up correctly in my build phases->copy bundle resources

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Remove the dot in the extension.

Comment: @wdetac it should return a path not nil

Comment: @vadian still gets the same error

Comment: Look at the built ipa file and confirm there really is a Songs folder with the mp3 file you expect.

Comment: @rmaddy where can I find that? I’m a noob I know

Comment: In Xcode go to the file project tree on the left. Open the Products folder and find your .app listed. Right click and select "Show In Finder". Then in Finder, right click on the .app and choose "Show Package Contents".

Comment: Remove the dot `.` at `ofType` param value. It will be fine.  

Edit: Check `Target Membership` of your files / folders in `File Inspector`, remmeber to ☑️check the targets you want.

Comment: @ngbaanh Please read the first 2nd and 4th comment.

Comment: @rmaddy the correct folder and files are there

Comment: What is the exact value for `songs[indexPath.row]`? Make sure the filename case matches. Make sure there are no unexpected whitespace. Make sure it doesn't include the .mp3 part of the name.

Comment: @rmaddy .mp3 was it thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I replied in the comment above but I should go to this place to upload the image and recap my opinion again:

- make sure you removed the dot `.`: `mp3` instead of `.mp3`
- `songs[indexPath.row]` *value* must not be optional, because it can cause a string like this: `Optional(MyFileName)`, and the value must not contains the extension `.mp3`, just filename only.
- Look at the picture below, if you `Bundle.main` equivalence is not a selected target in the list of File Inspector, the `audioPath` may be `nil`. So you have to check them for all of your mp3 files.

[image]